# Trying to go on holiday to Australia with my fiancé and daughter

Tags: visa-refusals, australia

My partner has booked a 4-week holiday in Australia in order to visit her god parent in Sydney, and then go to the Great Barrier Reef. I applied for an ETA visa, but was refused one as I have a criminal record (I served 7 months of an 18-month sentence, 20 years ago). I am worried that if I try to get a regular visitor visa, I will again be refused. We are supposed to leave on the 24th of December.

Do you think I will have time to get a visa?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Can you please add more information on what you want from us. As it stands this question is not very clear and already getting close votes.

Comment: I have edited your question for grammar and spelling. You will still need to add as much additional information as you can to help keep from being closed as "unclear".

Comment: Agree with @CGCampbell and altered the question to, perhaps, reopen and allow a response.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was created when you applied for the [ETA, for which you were ineligible](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETAS3/etas), as it notes that

> You must not have any criminal convictions for which you have been sentenced for a total combined period of 12 months or more, whether or not the sentence/s were served.

Now, you will have to [apply for a visitor visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-) and pay any applicable fee.

The encouraging bit is that, while strict, [Commonwealth of Australia entry requirements state](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Citi/Appl/What-documents-do-you-need/good-character-and-offences) that

> **You must declare all spent convictions when you complete your application form.**
>
> The spent convictions law allows people with minor convictions to disregard those convictions after a certain period of time. A conviction may be considered spent if:
>
> - it is 10 years since the date of the conviction (or five years for juvenile offenders)
> - the person was not sentenced to imprisonment or was not sentenced to imprisonment for more than 30 months
> - the person has not re-offended during the 10 years (or five years for juveniles) period
>
> The department is allowed to ask you for this information for the purpose of assessing your application.

As @pnuts has noted, do it immediately (and carefully).

Answer (score 5):

**do you think i will have time to get a visa**

Yes, 53 days or so seems enough to find out one way or another.

> The Visitor Visa usually takes approximately 20 days to be processed from the date that it is applied for. However, additional documentation may be required to complete your application which could significantly delay the process.

From [Australian Visa Bureau](http://www.visabureau.com/australia/tourist-visas.aspx).